# Toggle Hidden function with C# code Excel-Dna

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I am experimenting with [Excel-DNA](https://excel-dna.net/) and I am trying to find a way to toggle the IsHidden attribute of a custom function but I can't because it is a constant attribute

```
[ExcelFunction(name = "test", Description = "test function", IsHidden = SomeVar)]
```

I want to hide them when a setting is set by the user and toggle them back to visible when that setting is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution of the `IsHidden` property is done at compilation time. If the setting you need to check needs to happen at runtime, then your best bet is register the functions yourself using the custom registration https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration

Comment: Is there a way to access in the runtime the registered function that build in the compilation process?

Comment: Yes, via `GetExcelFunctions` - https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration/blob/master/Source/ExcelDna.Registration/Registration.cs#L26